# Check for changed properties in Play Framework Model during save

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm trying to implement some functionality where if a certain property on one of my model classes changes then execute some additional logic. I'm thinking that overriding the save and update methods in the model class is the way to go, but how to check for if a property has changed?  I see that Ebean has BeanPersistListener but that seems like it might be overkill for what I need here.

```java
public class Test extends Model {
    public String foo;
    public String bar;

    @Override
    public void save() {
        //if foo has been modified do something extra
        super.save();
    }

    //same thing for update()

}
```

Comment: `this._ebean_getIntercept().getChangedProps();` should give you all the changed properties before `update()`-ing, but ofcourse this is `null` if called before saving, but cant every non-null value before saving be considered as 'changed' ? If you need to catch every change of a property and not only before updating and saving, you can do `this._ebean_getIntercept().addPropertyChangeListener("foo",this);`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this as follows:

```
boolean isDirty = EbeanServer.getDefaultServer()
                             .getBeanState(yourObject)
                             .isNewOrDirty();
```